# Valgrind Android Error logwrapper

Tags: android, valgrind, root

Since I have errors when I set the gcc optimizations, I want to look precisely at the memory of my android application. For this I am trying to run valgrind.

I have install valgrind via termux, since it provides the package (no need to compile it then). But the error is sooner.

I have this script :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo "in the shell script"
touch /sdcard/ok.txt
VGPARAMS='--error-limit=no'
export TMPDIR=/data/data/com.gaulois94
exec /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/valgrind $VGPARAMS $*
```

And I do this :

```
adb shell
su
chmod 777 /data/local/valgrind.sh
setenforce 0
setprop wrap.com.gaulois94 "logwrapper /data/local/valgrind.sh"
```

But when running the application, my tablet (NVIDIA Shield Nougat) crashes and restarts... The echo and the touch have not even been executed...

Here are the error on am start :

```
    android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:3121)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:635)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:388)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

How can I run valgrind ? Thank you ! (this thing is making me crazy xd).

ps : don't know why, I can't say Hello at the beggining of the text... Well I put it here : Hello !

Comment: Another error : Sending non-protected broadcast eu.chainfire.supersu.NativeAccess from system uid 0 pkg null

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I didn't success launching valgrind on my tablet, though I could (after some hours) launch valgrind on a android x86 emulator, image system 22 (android 5.0).

Couldn't on ARM because of graphical issue (I use GLES2.0), and genymotion was just freezing when seeing the logwrapper.

If someone has a solution about my tablet though it would be wonderful !

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but it may helpful to someone.

1. On android device and setprop wrap.<> " " method could not be run below Android 8.0.
   So, I recommend to use 8.0 or higher.
   Actually I'm not sure it for 100%. I solved Dead Object Exception by using 8.0.
2. [Regardless] You must care about the carriage return char \x, if you work in windows.
   Make sure to use line feed char only for new line in script.